# Grep exact match returns matches with periods, spaces, hyphens, etc

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
... | grep -w "2015"
2015%kjlia
hi 2015.halteriafu
etc-2015
...
```

I want my grep to return lines with "2015" exact matches.

In original data there can be any characters before and after 2015.
The above only omitted a few lines like ..yguj2015vj.. with 2015 having adjacent alphanumeric character.

Comment: Its extremely unclear what you want. Edit your question to provide a clear testable example including sample input that has text you do and do not want found and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MAY be what you want:

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])2015([[:space:]]|$)' file
```

If not edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `-w`. That flag searches for whole *words*, where a word is `2015` not surrounded by any alphanumeric characters (exactly as you describe).

Or use `-x` to match the entire line.

Comment: That returns all lines with xx2015xx. That's not what I want.

Comment: What DO you want, then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
egrep '(^| )2015( |$)' file.txt
```

It finds "2015" surrounded by spaces.  It doesn't finds "2015" surrounded by tabs though.