# Is there a way to find an occurrence of a word delimited by space using a grep command?

Tags: grep

I need to find specific phrases within a text file using the grep commands. The first word must have a maximum of three letters, and there must be the word "of" delimited before and after by a space.
This is the example of the file text:

```
sch of aock
sch of rock
sc of uok
Tre schoof ai rock
Bamam school of aiao
Bam school of ciao
```

The correct result should be

```
sch of aock
sch of rock
sc of uok
Bam school of ciao
```

My code works only partially

```
grep -E '^.{0,3} of *' es1.txt
sch of aock
sch of rock
sc of uok

grep -E '^.{0,3} .* of ' es1.txt
Bam school of ciao
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep exact match returns matches with periods, spaces, hyphens, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814298/grep-exact-match-returns-matches-with-periods-spaces-hyphens-etc)

Comment: `grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])of([[:space:]]|$)' es1.txt`

Comment: It is not just a question of finding a word delimited by spaces, but a set of commands that modify the search. Putting [[:space:]] does not solve the problem. The conflict as explained below arises with the first condition

Comment: If you read the question title you will agree it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ grep -E '^\S{1,3} (.* )?of ' es1.txt
```

The first part makes sure you're looking at non-blanks for the first word, and that it has at least one character. Then, it's followed by a space.

Then you have optionally more words, however many, ending in a space. But that group is using a `?`, because it's not present when the word "of" is following the first word directly.

Finally, you're matching the word "of" and one more space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this simple regex solution (grep or awk):

```
grep -E '^.{1,3} .*of ' file
awk '/^.{1,3} .*of /' file
sch of aock
sch of rock
Tre schoof ai rock
Bam school of ciao
```

- `^` start with
- `.{1,3}` 1 to 3 character and space
- `.*` som more character
- `of` word of

Comment: The first word must have a maximum of three letters but also a minimum of 1 letter. Using your command you only take sentences whose first word has exactly three letters

Comment: The solution is still not right. The condition was that before and after "of" there is space. Tree schoof ai rock should not stay in the final result. So the solution should be: '.* of '. But it goes in conflict with the first condition as explained by filbranden